# Finding out which object/array uses most stack memory

Tags: c++, memory, stack-overflow

How can I find out which array/object/etc is the most gluttonous user of the stack memory?

---

Note : below is the original context to the question. Since then, I realised I had severe misunderstandings on how the stack works.

I have a bugged program that ends in a segfault. The segfault is caused by a variable being overwritten with non-sensical values out of the blue… That variable is in stack memory.

Hence my understanding is that I have an overflow of the stack memory at some other point of the program that corrupts the values of variables in the beginning of the next stack memory buffer.

However, valgrind doesn't show any error/warning (when launched with --leak-checks=yes) before encountering the segfault.

Hence a solution would be to find which objects/arrays/etc uses most of the stack memory and move them to heap memory.

Comment: That's would help if the problem was a stack overflow, but that doesn't sound like what's happening here. The problem description suggests a bad pointer or an array index out of bounds.

Comment: If you're on a Mac you can use Instruments. Otherwise you can try using [Massif](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473438/how-can-i-use-valgrind-for-memory-profile)

Comment: In my opinion, it doesn't sound like a stack overflow, but rather, writing to an array out of its bounds, overwriting neighboring values, placed on stack.

Comment: I set a watchpoint (using gdb) on the memory location of the variable being overwritten. It turns out to be (illegally) accessed upon instantiation of an object. So I suspect there is little chance of it to be caused by an out-of-bound array or by a bad pointer, and perhaps more by a stack overflow… (That's not a strong argument though)

Comment: If instantiating an object writes out of bounds the problem is in the object's constructor, most likely a bad pointer or an array index out of bounds.

Comment: @PeteBecker all right, I will follow your advice and have a second look on this.

Comment: I did not find the root of the problem but I managed to find a hack around. I know this is a (very) bad practice, but I'll stay content with that : tomorrow is a long day and I'd rather spend some time in bed tonight… I hope this is not going to sound too disappointing to you guys… Thanks for the help, I learned several things tonight !

Comment: @Claudiu you gave me the answer to my original question. I suggest you make it a regular answer (and not a comment) and I'll be happy to "validate" it !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're developing on a Mac, then you can use [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/index.html), which has a memory profiler that tells you where memory was allocate it and aggregates based on that.

Otherwise, you can use valgrind's [Massif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473438/how-can-i-use-valgrind-for-memory-profile) tool

If you're on a Mac you can use Instruments. Otherwise you can try using [Massif](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473438/how-can-i-use-valgrind-for-memory-profile). Sample output from the [Massif manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/ms-manual.html):

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  n        time(B)         total(B)   useful-heap(B) extra-heap(B)    stacks(B)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 10         10,080           10,080           10,000            80            0
 11         12,088           12,088           12,000            88            0
 12         16,096           16,096           16,000            96            0
 13         20,104           20,104           20,000           104            0
 14         20,104           20,104           20,000           104            0
99.48% (20,000B) (heap allocation functions) malloc/new/new[], --alloc-fns, etc.
->49.74% (10,000B) 0x804841A: main (example.c:20)
| 
->39.79% (8,000B) 0x80483C2: g (example.c:5)
| ->19.90% (4,000B) 0x80483E2: f (example.c:11)
| | ->19.90% (4,000B) 0x8048431: main (example.c:23)
| |   
| ->19.90% (4,000B) 0x8048436: main (example.c:25)
|   
->09.95% (2,000B) 0x80483DA: f (example.c:10)
  ->09.95% (2,000B) 0x8048431: main (example.c:23)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a watchpoint to find when memory is written

Comment: This, at least in my opinion, should have been a comment.

Comment: @mksteve, I already tried that, but I don't think the variable that overflows first is the root of the problem. I believe that there is a variable somewhere in my program that consumes too much stack memory but does not cause the stack overflow directly. Instead it restricts the available stack memory to such an extent that the other variables have too little left. Now, how do I find the variable responsible for the problem ?

Comment: @GLorieul If the available stack memory gets so restricted that _other variables have too little left_, they will, eventually, try to use more stack space than it is available, which would result in stack overflow, rather than overwrite of variables.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius you mean that stack overflow causes crash of the program and not overwriting of variables in adjacent stack buffer ?

Comment: @GLorieul Yes, that's precisely what I am saying. And, what do you mean by _adjacent stack buffer_? Your program has _the_ stack, not multiple _stack buffers_.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius sorry I was confused with how the stack works… I thought it was split into smaller sections called "buffers", but now I realise that I was quite off from reality… There is one stack and stack overflow is what happens when too much memory is requested for the stack. When that happens, the program starts accessing/writing to memory that hasn't been allocated to it by the OS. As a consequence the program crashes… Is that correct ?